# Emission shader on large object is black in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, emission

Starting with a new scene, I inserted a UV sphere with a 5028' radius (1 mile). In edit mode, I removed the bottom half making it a dome, then flipped the normals inside.

Then I added an emission shader. In cycles, it's just black, no matter how much I turn up the light/emission power. It works OK in Eevee. I also can't get point lights bright enough to hit the dome.

It works fine if the dome is 100', so this has something to do with the scale. I changed camera clipping to 30k feet, and I also set clamping in cycles to 0 for both. I wonder if there is a "light clip" setting somewhere? I also tried using the light falloff node with constant and the maximum strength it would allow.

I'd post a picture, but it's just black....

How do I get an emission shader to work on a giant object and/or from a great distance?

2.82a

UPDATE:

Here is a test file:

[image]

There is no scene camera, just the viewport camera with cycles enabled. the camera is position inside the dome.

Comment: Hello :). Works just fine on my end. Make sure to increase camera *and viewport* clipping distance. You can also [.share the .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Added a test file to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### As for your... uh... missing(?) light

The default world shader, and an example object;

[image]

Your file when first opened;

[image]

Disconnecting... whatever you were trying to do there;

[image]

Adding a default cube;

[image]

Decreasing the strength of your dome's emission... significantly;

[image]

[image]

### As for the point light question

I disconnected the emission (which generates light) and replaced it with a diffuse;

[image]

Then I added a point light at a minimally affecting strength (for the size of the dome;

[image]

Something a little stronger;

[image]

And especially stronger;

[image]

### Conclusion

I honestly have no idea what your goal is, or if I've answered your question properly. Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like the issue was related to the world shader. The goal was to have the light passing through fog that reduces the distance visibility/clarity.